# Can't figure out what I am missing?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use a subquery that returns the monetary values of all orders that have discounts greater than 15%.
List the orderid and the order value this last with the highest value at the top

Here is what I entered:

```
SELECT SUM(od.orderid) As OrderID,
AS [Order Values]
FROM [Order Details] od
WHERE od.Discount =
    (SELECTod.Discount
    FROM [Order Details] od
    GROUP BY od.discount
    HAVING od.discount >.15)
GROUP BY od.quantity, od.discount, od.UnitPrice
ORDER BY [Order Values] ASC;
```

Here is what I got:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, > => or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really dont need a subquery here anyway

```
 SELECT OrderID, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) OrderTotal
 FROM dbo.[Order Details]
 WHERE Discount > 0.15
 GROUP BY OrderID
 ORDER BY OrderTotal DESC
```

**With Sub query**

```
 SELECT OrderID, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) OrderTotal
 FROM dbo.[Order Details]
 WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID 
                   FROM dbo.[Order Details]
                   WHERE Discount > 0.15)
 GROUP BY OrderID
 ORDER BY OrderTotal DESC
```

**Using EXISTS Operator**

```
 SELECT OD.OrderID, SUM(OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity) OrderTotal
 FROM dbo.[Order Details] OD
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.[Order Details]
               WHERE OrderID = OD.OrderID
               AND Discount > 0.15)
 GROUP BY OD.OrderID
 ORDER BY OrderTotal DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `WHERE` clause. You're using `=` for multiple values, but that operator only allows for 1 value. So change this:

```
WHERE od.Discount =
    (SELECT od.Discount
    FROM [Order Details] od
    GROUP BY od.discount
    HAVING od.discount >.15)
```

To this:

```
WHERE od.Discount IN
    (SELECT od.Discount
    FROM [Order Details] od
    GROUP BY od.discount
    HAVING od.discount >.15)
```

or this:

```
WHERE od.Discount =
    (SELECT TOP 1 od.Discount
    FROM [Order Details] od
    GROUP BY od.discount
    HAVING od.discount >.15
    ORDER BY od.Discount DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE IN`, instead of `WHERE =`
That should handle multiple values returned from subquery

```
SELECT SUM(od.orderid) As OrderID,
AS [Order Values]
FROM [Order Details] od
WHERE od.Discount IN
    (SELECT od.Discount
    FROM [Order Details] od
    GROUP BY od.discount
    HAVING od.discount >.15)
GROUP BY od.quantity, od.discount, od.UnitPrice
ORDER BY [Order Values] ASC;
```